# Relación n_n en Codeigniter da error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

**Bueno pues siguiendo el tutorial de la página de codeigniter he intentado realizar una conexión muchos a muchos con tres tablas de la base de datos sin tener éxito. El caso es que quiero en mi tabla se muestren las tareas, la fecha de las tareas y los alumnos a los que se les encomienda dicha tarea. Pero ni siguiendo el tutorial ni nada sale como quiero. Las tablas son: Alumno, Tarea_alumno y Tarea.**

**La base de datos(Alumno / Tarea_alumno / Tarea)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El código**

```
public function tareas_alumno_lista() {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        //$crud->unset_bootstrap();
        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /
        $datos = array(
            'title' => "cursos", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );


        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        $crud->set_language("spanish");

        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
        $crud->set_table('tarea');

        //En 'nombreAlumno' saldrá el nombre del alumno que tiene encomendada dicha tarea
        $crud->set_relation_n_n('alumnos','tarea_alumno','tarea','Alumno_idAlumno','Tarea_idTarea','nombreTarea','idTarea_alumno');

        //los alumnos son necesarios para que muestre los alumnos existentes en dicha tarea
        $crud->fields('Nombre Tarea','Fecha Tarea','Alumnos');
        //$crud->required_fields('nombreTarea','fechaTarea');
        $crud->columns('nombreTarea','fechaTarea','nombreAlumno');


        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_example_output($output);
    }
```

Comment: Estas aprendiendo Codeigniter, te recomiendo que mejor aprendas Laravel.
Debes de seguir el patron MVC, Necesitas enviar el codigo de tu modelo, vista y controlador.

Comment: No eres el primero que me lo comenta, pero para este ejercicio me pedían Codeigniter, me gustaría ponerme con Laravel ya que todos hablan muy bien de él. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relacion yo la haria asi;

```
//Tareas_model.php
<?php
class Tareas_model extends CI_Model{

   public function getPacientes($id)
   {
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM Tare_alumno ta
        LEFT JOIN Tarea t on t.idTarea = ta.Tarea_idAlumno
        LEFT JOIN Alumno a on a.idAlumno = ta.Alumno_idAlumno
        WHERE a.IdAlumno = '.$id.';');
      $html = '';
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){          
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
         {
            $html .= '<p>Tarea: '.$row->nombreAlumno.' </p>
            <p>Fecha: '.$row->fechaTarea.' </p>
            ';
         }
         return $html;
      }else{
         $html .= 'No hay datos';
         return $html;
      }
   }   

}
```

El modelo lo pasas al controlador y del controlador a la vista.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, en realidad buscaba algo como esto http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation_n_n  pero me sirve, muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta.

Comment: Oh ya, estas usando un ORM, te recomiendo: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html